# Restarting Remote Kernels when using IPython.parallel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel

How do I force the remote kernels to restart when I am using IPython.parallel?

For example in the normal IPython notebook, I can restart a kernel right from the [tool bar](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/notebook.html#basic-workflow). My question is when I have remote kernels, how do I force the same operation?

Answer (score 1):

[Saw another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772326/how-to-reduce-ipython-parallel-memory-usage) from @drevicko that might get at what you want, even if it doesn't actually answer the specific question you posted about restarting the engines. Would purging the engine have the desired effect for your case?

```
Client.purge_everything()
Client.purge_hub_results(jobs=[], targets=[])
Client.purge_results(jobs=[], targets=[])
Client.abort(jobs=None, targets=None, block=None)
```